# stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: ubuntu, php, php-fpm, openssl

I've recently upgraded a server from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 and since the upgrade I've been receiving the following error when try to send mail via SMTP or when trying to connect to an S3 bucket with PHP 7.0.

```
stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14161044:SSL routines:state_machine:internal error
```

Having tried every solution on stack exchange I've not had much luck. I've tried adding the following to my openssl.cnf:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

However this hasn't helped and I'm still receiving these errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OpenSSL's error messages are somewhat cryptic. Try from the command line with s_client

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this issue in PHPMailer after migrating from php 5.5 to php 5.6. The issue is to do with default TLS version used by openssl. I am not an expert in openssl, but here is the solution that worked for me.

The error logged in my php error log was

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:14161044:SSL routines:state_machine:internal error in /var/www/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php on line 319
```

The code in line 319 of `class.smtp.php` in PHPMailer uses crypto_type `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT`,

```php
if (! stream_socket_enable_crypto ( $this->smtp_conn, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT )) {
  return false;
}
```

I changed crypto_type from `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT` to `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT`, see php documentation for available crypto_types https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-enable-crypto.php

```php
if (! stream_socket_enable_crypto ( $this->smtp_conn, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT )) {
 return false;
}
```

This change solved the error for me.  I am not sure if this issue occurred   due to the upgrade of OpenSSL (OpenSSL 1.0.1f  to OpenSSL 1.1.1f) or PHP (PHP 5.5.9 to PHP 5.6.4)

I had tried many other changes before i found this solution. So these changes may also have contributed to my final solution.

1. I tried setting the following in PHPMailer, this did not work

```php
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT
    )
);
```

2. Also I added the following to my openssl.cnf, this did not work either

```
openssl_conf = default_conf 

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Answer (score 1):

@Swisstone's answer contains the fix (using crypto method `STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT`), however it contains an example only for when explicitly calling `stream_socket_enable_crypto`. If you are using `stream_socket_client` directly then you need to define a context and pass it as a parameter:

```
    $contextOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
        ),
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);
    $sock = stream_socket_client($address, $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
```